# Seeking Strategies to Enhance Facebook Ad Conversions for E-Commerce in the US and UK Markets

Tags: ads, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-ads, google-advertising-id

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm in need of insights to improve Facebook advertising outcomes for izemporium.com, our e-commerce site dedicated to South Asian and Pakistani fashion. Despite offering competitive prices and ensuring a seamless shopping experience, our campaigns targeting the US and UK markets haven't met expected conversion rates.

Campaign Strategy:
We've implemented both Advantage+ shopping campaigns and manual tactics, targeting engaged shoppers with interests in designer and cultural attire. Our efforts yield click-through rates of 4-6%, yet fail to convert interest into purchases, often encountering a "zero purchases" warning for these regions.

Challenges & Efforts:

Localization: Our ads, tailored for izemporium.com, aim to resonate with the US and UK audience's cultural and fashion preferences.
Targeting: We focus on fashion enthusiasts keen on Pakistani and designer clothing, enhancing our campaigns for better engagement.
Engagement: By maximizing clicks and interaction, we hoped to drive higher conversion rates.
Key Questions:

Ad Content Localization: How can we further refine our ad content to align with US and UK audience expectations and preferences?
Audience Targeting: What adjustments can improve our targeting strategy to boost engagement and conversions in these markets?
Ad Formats & Placements: Which ad formats and placements have proven effective for fashion e-commerce platforms in the US and UK?
Website Optimizations: Are there potential site enhancements that could uplift izemporium.com's conversion rates?
Despite our targeted and engagement-focused strategies, the disconnect between click-through rates and actual conversions prompts a need for a revised approach. I'm eager to learn from those who've navigated similar challenges or have relevant expertise.

Thank you for your time and insights.

Best regards,